# How to get 24 hours number from System.DateTime.Now.Hour?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get the current hour number with `0-24` from  `System.DateTime.Now.Hour`. 
I am not sure if it will return an integer between `0-12` or `0-24`.
How do I make sure I will get an integer between `0-24`?

Comment: `Not sure it will return a integer between 0-12 or 0-24?` You should start by writing a simple program that displays the `Hour` value of any time after noon and finding out.  Or you could read the relevant documentation in `DateTime`.

Comment: It will never return 24.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx - *"The hour component, expressed as a value between 0 and 23."*

Comment: int HH = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH"));

Answer (score 69):

[**DateTime.Hour Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx)

> The value of the Hour property **is always expressed using a 24-hour
>   clock**. To retrieve a string that represents the hour of a date and
>   time using a 12-hour clock, call the DateTime.ToString(String) or
>   DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) method with the "h" custom
>   format specifier. For example:

and

> The hour component, expressed as a value between **0 and 23**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a specific string version of a DateTime object I suggest using either a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) or a [standard date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

I usually use `dateTimeVar.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ffff zzz");` though you may want `K` instead of `zzz`

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN;

```
   DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 1, 18, 53, 0);
   Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("%h"));              // Displays 6 
   Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("h tt"));            // Displays 6 PM
```